# Why is this Media Query for mobile interfering with desktop styling?

Tags: css, media-queries

I never had an issue before but all of a sudden 1 day it changed and now I see the mobile CSS effecting the desktop. I tried to do a display:none; in there to hide everything but nothing happens... any ideas?

**Here's the link tag**

```
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="{PATH_TO_STUFF}/css/small.css" type="text/css" media="all" />`
```

**Here's the css media query.**

```
@media screen and (max-width:480px) {
/* stuff in here */
}
```

Comment: You'll need to post more code to be sure. My guess is that the order you have your media queries defined in your CSS is causing this issue.

Comment: My guess is that you are missing a closing bracket, put your css through lint

Comment: Post more code, what you have is fine.